# Cutting a section out of a string and returning the opposite

Tags: regex, bash, glob

Given a directory tree, how would I go about cutting the last field of the delimiter out of the string and returning the string without that delimiter, assuming I don't know where that string ends?

For instance, given

```
/1/2/3/4/5
```

I know I can return 5 with

```
cut -f 5 -d '/'
```

if I know the last field is the 5th one, or if a=/1/2/3/4/5

```
echo ${a##*/}
```

to pick the last field. But how would I go about returning the original string minus the last field? ie

```
/1/2/3/4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `%` or `%%` operator instead of `##`.  From the Bash man-page:

> ```
>  ${parameter%word}
>  ${parameter%%word}
>           The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as  in  pathname  expan-
>           sion.   If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded value
>           of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of
>           parameter  with  the  shortest matching pattern (the ``%'' case) or the
>           longest matching pattern (the ``%%'' case) deleted.  If parameter is  @
>           or  *,  the  pattern  removal  operation  is applied to each positional
>           parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parame-
>           ter  is  an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the pattern removal
>           operation is applied to each member of  the  array  in  turn,  and  the
>           expansion is the resultant list.
> ```

In short, `${a%/*}` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can give cut a range of fields

```
cut -f 1-4 -d '/'
```